# Chrome driver block image extension freeze the page?

Tags: c#

With the new Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.74.0.3729.6 update, the problem came out.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-image/pehaalcefcjfccdpbckoablngfkfgfgj?hl=tr

I'm trying to use the extension above.

```
ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddExtensions(@Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\block-image.crx");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

run the program. My result page remains "data :,". does not go to the page I want. different extensions have tried the same unfortunately.

Comment: Watch out, C and C# are different languages.

Comment: I'm using c#...

Comment: I know, it's just you tagged the question with C